# Playwright how to click a specific element if there's lot found?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I having a hard time clicking 3rd element found. I tried index, and .third() method still not working.

Test Result:
[Test Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF1hL.png)

```html
    async clickAddToCart(page) {
        const element = commonEl.addToCart();
        await page.evaluate((el) => document.querySelector(el)[3].click(), element)
    }
```

```html
 addToCart() {
        return ('.bg-blue-500.text-white.font-semibold.rounded-md');
    }
```

Trying to get this element
[Trying to get this element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC5Kh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `nth` selector for this. For the third button you have to use the index value as 2.

```js
await page.locator('button.py-4 >> nth=2').click();
```